# Django view as API with Get method save twice records from Firefox

Tags: django, django-views, idempotent

I made a simple view for searching one product in my ecommerce website..

The view (an API) wait a GET parameter (as http://example.com/search/12345) after I would like to save the searched parameter (with a create queryset) in a specific model for obtain search history.

But if I call the view/api from last Firefox version, I get two records in database, from Edge only one.

Deepening the topic the problem is the idempotency expected from HTTP RFC on Get method.
Some browsers can do more than one request...

I need to preserve GET method for search api but I need saving the searched string.

What can I use GET parameter for searching and SAVE it in database only one? without CSRF/Cookie/User-Agent?

For better understanding the code very simplified:

```
# models.py
class SearchHistory(models.Model):

    searched_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    results_number = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.searched_text}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "search term"
        verbose_name_plural = "history search terms"

#url.py
urlpatterns = [
      ...
      path('search/<str:search>', search, name='search'),
      ...
]

# views.py
def search(request, search):
    products = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=search)
    results_number = len(products) # I know a better way for this..
    SearchHistory.objects.create(searched_text=search, results_number=results_number)
    return HttpResponse('irrilevant ... :-)')
```

Comment: may you provide your model and API too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I had a bad img tag in my template.

The offending element:

```
<img src="#" />
```

When Firefox read this element in DOM, reload page.